# How do I represent a 32 bit binary by using 8 characters?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, binary, hex, bit-manipulation

I'm looking at memory addresses which are 32 bits. How do I represent them using 8 digits/characters - such as '0x12345678'?
How many bits does each character represent? What is this system called?
How can I convert a decimal integer value to this format in Python?

Comment: It is just an hexadecimal (much more handy for addresses, because processors works on binary basis). I think you should check Wikipedia: there are so many related things, which may be impossible to answer here (without getting on unnecessary details, or being too generic). Just nobody uses decimal for addresses, and few people do arithmetic with addresses (manually, without writing them down). On a decimal number, how many bits are represented by every digit? How do you read it with Python? Start with decimal (which is also non-trivial).